# Rename all directories after matching

Tags: linux, shell, rename

I'm looking for a way to rename all these directories from:

```
1_20_10 
1_20_20 
1_20_30 
1_20_40
```

to:

```
2_20_10 
2_20_20 
2_20_30 
2_20_40
```

I tried this command:

```
mv /1_20*/ /2_20*/
```

and the rename command but doesn't work.

Comment: Easy with zmv from zsh: `zmv "1_(*)" "2_$1"`

Comment: Why not use a `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a substitution with `sed` and iterate with a `for` loop.

```sh
for i in 1_*; do 
   mv $i $(sed -En 's/^1_(.*)/2_\1/p' <<< $i); 
done
```

Comment: Why not `mv "$i" "2_${i#*_}"`?

Comment: Is also a solution. I shared the one I recalled at first glance.